# Can't then a promise return by a function - jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using the [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) library to do some image manipulation. Stepping through the `read` method I see the last line hit is the one returning a promise. As soon as it returns, the `.then` throws an error as though the promise was never returned from `read`.

The error: **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Source code from jimp (clearly returning a promise):

```
Jimp.read = function(src, cb) {
    var promise = new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            cb = cb || function(err, image) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(image);
            }
            if ("string" != typeof src && ("object" != typeof src || !Buffer.isBuffer(src)))
                return throwError.call(this, "src must be a string or a Buffer", cb);
            var img = new Jimp(src, cb);
        }
    );
    return promise;
}
```

My code:

```
var jimp = require('jimp');
var nano = require('nano');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Common = require('../models/Common');
var util = require('../utils/helper');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.changeLogo = function changeLogo(user, file) {
    var theFile = file.destination + file.filename; //file.path?

    jimp.read(theFile).then(function(logo) {
        fs.unlink(theFile);
        logo.resize(jimp.AUTO, 150)

        logo.getBuffer(file.mimetype, function(err, buffer) {

            return Common.addAttachment(user, 'logo' + util.getFileExtension(file.filename), buffer, file.mimetype);
        })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    })

};
```

I break before running jimp.read(theFile), and run this in console:

```
var test = jimp.read(theFile);
test;
```

This gives me `#<Promise>`

typeof test here is an object.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ssube Sorry, just edited it in

Comment: In one place you write `Jimp` and the other it's `jimp`. Are you sure you're referencing the right function?

Comment: How and when did you declare `jimp` (the lower case one). In short, how is the Jimp namespace defined? Is it a plain object that you just alias to `jimp`, or a class where you're trying to do `var jimp = new Jimp()`?

Comment: @SterlingW var jimp = require('jimp'); I think the read method should be returning a new instance through the promise's resolved value.

Comment: @Elliot It [looks like it should work](https://tonicdev.com/5771924144e49613003f1ad1/5771924144e49613003f1ad2) so you must be doing something you're not showing us.

Comment: @MikeC Yeah I see that. I uploaded my entire module now.

Comment: @Elliot I don't see anything in there that would do it. Perhaps you should try doing `console.log(jimp)` and `console.log(jimp.read)` and see what you get. Might give you a clue as to what's changing.

Comment: I would try what @MikeC suggested. It looks like jimp will be undefined.

Comment: I checked that and Jimp is not undefined. I stepped through and it goes all the way through the read method and returns an actual promise.

Comment: What's Node.js version? To me this sounds more like a problem with Promise support

Comment: Using node v4.4.4. I use promises all over elsewhere without any problems.

Comment: @Elliot "returns an actual promise" So you're telling me that if you do `console.log(jimp.read(theFile))`, you're getting a promise back? Because you can't be getting the error you posted on the line you pointed to if that's the case.

Comment: If I break right before running jimp.read() and then run jimp.read(theFile) in the console, I am returned a promise '#<Promise>'.

Comment: And if you let it run through, it says that `jimp.read(theFile)` is `undefined`? You are 100% certain it's pointing at **that** line when it throws that error? Because that's impossible. If `jimp.read(theFile)` returns a Promise, it cannot be saying that you are trying to call `then` on `undefined`.

Comment: Change code to something similar to `var p = jimp.read(theFile); console.log(p); p.then(....`

Comment: @MikeC I edited my question adding info regarding this. But yes, it seems I'm getting a promise back when I call jimp.read(theFile)

Comment: @Elliot If you're getting a Promise back, and you're running a version of Node that has proper Promise support then your error is in another castle. Do what Kirill suggested and add an extra log for `p.then` (`console.log(p.then)`).

Comment: If your caller(s) call `.changeLogo(user, file).then(...)`, (a) it will certainly throw "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" because nothing is currently returned by `changeLogo()`; (b) `logo.getBuffer()` needs to be promisified to take account of *its* asynchronism.